# Validation Does not work when enter button is pressed but works on clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

My ajax call

```
    $("#go_btn").on('click',function(){

                $.ajax({

                      url: '<c:url value="/filter/save" />',

                      data: $('input,select',"#requestForm").not(".hint").serialize(),
                      type: 'POST',
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(data){                       

                          if(data.success == true){
                              $('.error',"#requestForm").hide().removeData('errorsData');

                              $("#requestForm").submit();

                          }else if(data.success == false){
                              $('.error',"#requestForm").hide().removeData('errorsData');
                              var errors = data.errors;               
                              for (var key in errors) {                  
                                    var errorDesc = errors[key];
                                    var $question = $('input[name="'+key+'"],select[name="'+key+'"]',"#requestForm").parents('td');
                                    var $errorDiv = $('div.error',$question);
                                    var errorsData = $errorDiv.data('errorsData'); 

                                    if(!errorsData){
                                        errorsData = new Array();                             
                                        $errorDiv.data('errorsData',errorsData);                          
                                    }

                                    errorsData[errorsData.length] = errorDesc;

                                    var errorHTML = '';
                                    for(var i=0 ; i < errorsData.length;i++){
                                        if(i>0){
                                              errorHTML += '<br />';
                                        }
                                        errorHTML += errorsData[i]; 

                                    }

                                    $('.error_message',$errorDiv).html(errorHTML);
                                    $errorDiv.show();

                                    $(this).scrollTop(0);
                                    $('input[name="'+key+'"]').focus();
                                    $('select[name="'+key+'"]').focus();

                                }
                          }
                      }       
                });
```

My HTML code

```
 <a href="#" title="click next" id="go_btn" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;">
```

The controller method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/filter/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)

@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> saveFilterDetails(
        @ModelAttribute(value = "bean") Bean bean,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {

    Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, String> fieldErrors = new HashMap<String, String>();

    if (bean.getIndustryId() == 0 || bean.getIndustryId() <= 0) {
        result.rejectValue("industryId", "bean.filter.industry.mandatory");
    }

    if (bean.getRoleId() == 0 || bean.getRoleId() <= 0) {
        result.rejectValue("roleId", "bean.filter.role.mandatory");
    }

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(result, "customerName",
            "bean.customername.mandatory");


    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        output.put("success", false);

        for (FieldError fieldError : result.getFieldErrors()) {
            try {
                String value = messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, null);
                fieldErrors.put(fieldError.getField(), value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        output.put("errors", fieldErrors);
        return output;
    }
    else
    {   
        output.put("success", true);

        return output;
    }

}
```

The validation works when user clicks the button but it does not work when user presses enter key. How to bind the enter key functionality to my code so that it works .

Edit:

my form

```
   <form:form id="requestForm" method="post" modelAttribute="bean" Action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/social" >
.
.
.
   <a href="#" title="click next" id="go_btn" style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;"> 
.
.
.
</form:form>
```

Comment: That's because you're using an `a` element to submit the form. Change that element to a submit button within the form and you'll get the behaviour by default.

Comment: but ajax call is not occuring when the input type i submit

Comment: Where is the input? You haven't included any relevant HTML

Comment: ihave now edited and added the html code

Comment: _"but ajax call is not occuring when the input type i submit"_ - you need to prevent the default, so that the form is not submitted the "normal" way. Go look it up, it has been written about countless times.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `<a>`-tag and insert a `<button type="submit">` instead.

Comment: That  + preventing the event.